# Javascript convert from UTC to local date time

Tags: javascript

I am getting a datetime that is in UTC. I like the result to show the datetime locally in the following format:

```
    September 18th 2013, 7:07:00 PM
```

Is there a function that can come close to this..

I tried the following but not the result I was looking for:

```
     var dt = new Date(date + " UTC");
     return dt.toString();
```

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: If you're just looking to choose the format, see "[Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/15031)."

Answer (score 0):

Different variations of this question have been asked many times before. Without knowing your input datatype for "date" the question is a little unclear. Please refer to this post, it should answer your question on formatting dates.

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this:

```
moment().format('LLL');  // Closest output will be like this :- October 9 2013 11:17 PM
```